# Calculated Field/Item in Excel Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

How can I create a % based on column and grand total.  I have a column named Offer and two fields in that column that says relevant and not relevant.  I want to show the percentage based on grand total.

Offer

Relevant    Not Relevant    Grand Total
455          3               458

I am looking to achieve something like this

Relevant    Not Relevant    Grand Total 
99%             1%           458

If I could do the number and percentage that would ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear on how your data are structured. In the PivotTable field, if you right click on the selected column, select Value Field Settings, and then "show values as," you can then show them as a percentage of the total.

See this for more:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-different-calculations-in-PivotTable-value-fields-014d2777-baaf-480b-a32b-98431f48bfec